# How to improve performance of Wpf DataGrid for high frequency cell updates (.net 4.5)?

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, wpfdatagrid

I am using a DataGrid control on a WPF Desktop application developed with C# 4.5. This datagrid has 150 rows and 5 colums. Each cell is updated about 2-3 times per minute using BeginInvoke with DispatcherPriority.Background. Here's the code snippet of the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Simulations, IsAsync=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                ColumnWidth="*" CanUserResizeRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSimulation}" 
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      EnableColumnVirtualization="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nome do Cenario Geológico" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=GeologicalScenarioName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Estado da Simulação" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=JobStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Link para pasta de trabalho" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=LocalFolderPath, IsAsync=True}">
                        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="SimulationHyperlinkClick"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanCancelSimulation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}" Click="ButtonBaseOnClickSim">Cancelar Simulação</Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tempo" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=TimeRunning, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The problem is that the UI is unresponsive due to the number of updates. Can someone give me a clue to how to improve the performance?

Thankx